# Proof of Pascal's Rule confusion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am reading *Elementary Number Theory 7th Edition* from David Burton. ([See here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005J0H3JW)) On page 8 he sets about to prove *Pascal's Rule*

$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1} = \binom{n+1}{k}$$

But then he says

> Its proof consists of multiplying the identity
>
> $$\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n-k+1}=\frac{n+1}{k(n-k+1)}\tag{1}$$
>
> by
>
> $$\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\tag{2}$$
>
> to obtain $$ \frac{n!}{k(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)(n-k)!}
>   =\frac{(n+1)n!}{k(k-1)!(n-k+1)(n-k)!} $$

which can then be rearranged into the factorial version of *Pascal's Rule*. Fine, but where did the "identity" expressions and the expression to multiply it by ($(1)$ and $(2)$) come from? Also, how is this a proof?

Comment: As we can see , we could just divide by $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ our first statement. And after this we will get (1).

Comment: Chicken or the egg? So then, where then does $\frac{n!}{(k-1)(n-k)!}$ come from?

Comment: they just miltiply by it. Some of "magic" constant which will help in task.

Comment: Because of it i want to say that this proof isn't pretty.

Comment: There must be a reason for the choices of (1) and (2). Otherwise, it's not a proof.

Comment: That's a proof because of logical. We have right equation (1) and we get from it (2). $a \to b$ , this implication give us the rule : if a s true , then b also true.

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k} |\cdot \frac{(k-1)!(n-k)!}{n!}$, so $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n-k+1} = \frac{n+1}{k(n-k+1)}$ which is true, so the statement is true.

---

But this looks awful. It have simple combinatorical proof:

$\binom{n+1}{k}$ - number of ways to select $k$ objects from $n+1$. Suppose we select one object , now we could get others with $\binom{n}{k-1}$ ways. But we also could not to get the first object and so there is $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select others.